# Yarn blatantly ignores the version I told it to install

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

```
# yarn global add -E @azure/storage-blob@10.5.0
yarn global v1.22.0
[1/4] �  Resolving packages...
[2/4] �  Fetching packages...
error @azure/storage-blob@12.14.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.0.0". Got "12.9.1"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

I have a project I need to get running locally that is not compatible with Node 14. So I need to install the old packages. If I can't get this package installed, the only other option is to find the laptop of our mobile developer who left years ago.

How do I make `yarn` install the version I told it to install instead of picking the version *it* wants to install? The `-E` option is supposed to tell `yarn` to install the exact version I specified, but it's not even sticking to the same major version.